# Show infowindow on marker in Gmap3

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I am using the jquery plugin Gmap3 to create a map. Right now I have successfully created a map with a marker with this code:

```
    $(window).load(function() {

  $('#my_map').gmap3({
     map:{
        options:{
         center:[36.140093,-115.174012],
         zoom:12,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         mapTypeControl: true,
         mapTypeControlOptions: {
           style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
         },
         streetViewControl:false,
         scaleControl: true
        }
     },
    marker:{
      latLng:[36.140093,-115.174012]
    }

  });

});
```

How can I put an info window on the marker's position?

Please let me know about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a sample code here

http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/10-overlays/marker-41